# Android 5.0 DatePicker with Theme.AppCompat

Tags: android, datepicker, android-appcompat, material-design

I'm trying to do an App with Material Design for previous versions of Android using Theme.AppCompat. 
I want to show the [lollipop DatePicker](http://material-design.storage.googleapis.com/publish/v_2/material_ext_publish/0Bx4BSt6jniD7M0Jrd1hyamhaZUk/components_dialogs_confirmation3.png) in this previous version, but nowadays my App DatePicker in  Android 4 devices is looking like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SzmcI.png).

**Code:**

The dialog call:

```
DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(),
                            new mDateSetListener(), mYear, mMonth, mDay);
                    dialog.show();
```

The DatePicker class:

```
 @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }

    class mDateSetListener implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                              int dayOfMonth) {
            int mYear = year;
            int mMonth = monthOfYear;
            int mDay = dayOfMonth;
            /*System.out.println(mYear);
            System.out.println(mMonth);
            System.out.println(mDay);*/


        }
    }
```

It's possible to show the Material Design DatePicker in previous versions like I want ?

Thx.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way to show a Material Design DatePicker Dialog on pre-lollipop devices is either to create your own Dialog or to use a library such as [this one](https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker).

Comment: How to configure DatePicker using support library so that it will show material DatePicker in pre-lollipop devices?

Comment: my bad, I forgot it was for pre-lollipop devices. You need to create your own or use a library in that case.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is old, but the accepted answer's lib uses an old material design, which I didn't like, so I back ported the official framework version (Oreo, 8.0) of the `DatePickerDialog` and `TimePickerDialog` using the appcompat library to work on API 14+.

The lib source is available [here](https://github.com/Gericop/DateTimePicker) and you can include it in your app from jCenter using gradle:

```
compile 'com.takisoft.fix:datetimepicker:1.0.0'
```